# Issues with exporting html to excel

Tags: php, html, excel

For exporting our reports, we set the header to 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=fileName.xls' and dump the html to the output buffer and it downloaded the excel file nice and clean.

This was used to work until recently and now the downloaded file does not open in Excel. It doesn't give any error, just shows the blank gray screen similar to the screen when you close all the worksheets.

**Strange enough, if you just open the file in Notepad++, add a space and save it, Excel WILL open it.**

I suspect it to be something to do w/ the encoding of the file which is not acceptable to excel when the file is downloaded but something changes after you edit it in Notepad++ and excel would open it after the edit.

I have tried using ob_clean(), trim and converted the content to utf8 before dumping but nothing seems to work, what am I doing wrong?

Here is a sample code that recreates the issue I have:

```
ob_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=filename.xls");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header_remove('Pragma');

// simple html table
echo '<table><thead><tr><td>header 1</td><td>header 2</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>content 1</td><td>content 2</td></tr></tbody></table>';
```

The above code snippet downloads the file 'filename.xls', excel initially does not open it, but after editing it the way I described earlier, excel WILL open it.

Thanks.

Comment: Without code, nobody is able to give you proper advices

Comment: Just edited the OP to include code snippet...

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, then searching i found this!

"The Excel team has made a change in the behavior of certain file types to increase security." On: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3181507

You can try one of the possible Solutions/Workaround.

Comment: This is great information. At least it helped me convince the client that the issue is at Microsoft and not in the app. Thanks a lot for sharing this. I don't have reputation enough to give it a +1, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the exel is blocking the unsafe document which downloads from internet.

To avoid this, you have change some settings in excel.
Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Protacted View

Untick the Enable Protected View for files originated from the internet.

Save it

That's it.

You can open the files.

Comment: You're right, but that's not a good fix. We have thousands of users, imagine reaching out to all of them to make this change to their Excel setting, and to convince them to "allow content from untrusted sources", its not a practical solution.

Comment: Hey, It's a temporary one. Not only you somany people are facing the same. If you dont want to convince client and thousand users better to use a proper excel plugin if not stick wih this coding style and wait until it get sorted.

Comment: Unfortunately, MS no longer supports exporting HTML to Word/Excel. Anyone who maybe wondering what did I do about my problem, I had to rewrite all my reports to export to native Excel format, for me, that was the only long lasting solution...